# Complete the last step in an analytic function proof

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series, analytic-functions

let $ f$  be analytic function in segment A. and assume $ \in A $ and $ f(0)=0 $

prove that exists  $ n \in N $ and analytic function  $ g(x) $  in segment A such that:

$ f(x)=x^n\cdot g(x) $ for any $ x∈A$

So, I want to prove that $ g $ is analytic in any point in segment $ A $

so, i can just define $ g= \frac{1}{x^{n}}f\left(x\right) $ and since f analytic and $ \frac{1}{x^n} $ analytic, g will be analytic in any point $ f $ is analytic, except $ x=0 $

so, we know that $ f(0)=0 $ and we can define $ g\left(0\right)=a_{n_{0}} $ 
when $ n_0 $ is the minimal index such $ a_{n_{0}}\neq0 $ in the power series $ f\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} $ around $x_0=0 $ 
so I've proved that g is analytic in any point except $ 0 $. how can i prove that its also analytic in x=0 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0)=0,$ it means the constant term in the power series for $f$ about $0$ vanishes. Thus it is enough to take $n=1,$ although some higher value of $n$ may exist. Then $g(x)$ is also a power series, which defines an analytic function perforce.

Comment: this does not explains why g is analytic by definition in every point $ a\in A $ its just explains why g is analytic in the segment $ (-\delta,\delta ) $ that we have from the fact that f analytic in 0

Comment: @Waizman Isn't $f$ analytic in $A$?

Comment: Maybe im confused, but as good as i know f analytic in A means that for every $x_0 \in A$ exists $ \delta>0 $ such that for every $ x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta $ we have $ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ so if you want to talk about the power series of f around 0 it only explains that g is anlytic in this segment of 0

Comment: @Waizman But doesn't $A$ include $0$?

Comment: But the power series of $ f $ around $ 0 $ does not necessarily converge in any $ x_0\in A $. for example $ \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} $ analytic in $ \mathbb{R} $ but its taylor series around $ 0 $ does not converge in whole $ \mathbb{R} $

Comment: @Waizman I see your point, although I'm curious about the specific example you gave. Can you give a series representation of that function outside the natural interval about $0$?

Comment: @Waizman In any case, my answer concludes your proof since you've already seen how to do points different from $0.$ You only need my idea to conclude your proof. Why do you think a proof cannot be in cases? Indeed, I think I thought you wanted to prove analyticity only about $0,$ which in fact turns out to be the case; so why are you unnecessarily being reluctant to accept the idea?

Comment: I tought that was suggestion to prove for any $ a\in A$ , Im trying to prove it by the definition, because we havent prooved yet the theorem "any convergent series defines analytic function in its convregnet radius. So i cant use it.

Comment: @Waizman Oh, my! No one will prove that to you because it's obvious! A convergent power series about $0$ obviously defines a function there. And that function is obviously represented by the series there. Don't expect a proof of any such result. It follows straight from the definition!

Comment: I see, so because $ g\left(0\right)=\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{\infty}a_{n}0^{n-n_{0}} $ and for any other x $ g\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n-n_{0}} $ i can conclude that g is anlytic in 0 by definition ?

Comment: @Waizman What I meant was that since about $x=0,$ we have that $f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nx^n$ for all $x\in A,$ and $f(0)=0,$ then we have that $0=f(0)=c_0,$ from the series. Thus $f$ is really of the form $$\sum_{n\ge 1}c_nx^n=x\sum_{x\ge 1}c_nx^{n-1}=xg(x).$$